# Adding a C# template to XAML code. How can I do the binding?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a C# class like this used in my application. It is a grid with four buttons.

If I view two buttons the output is:

[image]

If I view three buttons the output is:

[image]

Note that as the btn2 and btn3 are identical I can find now reason why two works and three does not:

```cs
public class PracticeButtons : Grid
{
    public PracticeButtons()
    {
        this.Padding = new Thickness(20, 0, 20, 0);

        var btn1 = new CardButtonTemplate()
        {
            ButtonBackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["IosRed"],
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
        btn1.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TapCommandProperty, new Binding("ABtnCmd"));
        btn1.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TextTopProperty, new Binding("ABtnTitleLabelTop"));
        btn1.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TextBtmProperty, new Binding("ABtnTitleLabelBtm"));

        var btn2 = new CardButtonTemplate()
        {
            ButtonBackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["IosOrange"],
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
        btn2.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TapCommandProperty, new Binding("BBtnCmd"));
        btn2.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TextTopProperty, new Binding("BBtnTitleLabelTop"));
        btn2.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TextBtmProperty, new Binding("BBtnTitleLabelBtm"));

        var btn3 = new CardButtonTemplate()
        {
            ButtonBackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["IosOrange"],
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
        btn3.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TapCommandProperty, new Binding("BBtnCmd", source: this));
        btn3.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TextTopProperty, new Binding("BBtnTitleLabelTop", source: this));
        btn3.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TextBtmProperty, new Binding("BBtnTitleLabelBtm", source: this));

        this.Children.Add(btn1, 0, 0);
        this.Children.Add(btn2, 1, 0);
        this.Children.Add(btn3, 2, 0); // commented when viewing 2 buttons
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems have no issue . Could you share your sample to github so that I can test it on my side directly ?

Comment: you are not setting the BindingContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Please remove "source:this" from btn3 set binding method.

```
btn3.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TextTopProperty, new Binding("BBtnTitleLabelTop"));
```

We can bind whole BindingContext object using "."

```
<Grid>
   <!--<buttons:CardPracticeButtons />-->
   <studycards:PracticeButtons BindingContext="{Binding .}"/>
</Grid>
```

**PracticeButtons**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace StudyCards
{
    public class PracticeButtons : Grid
    {
        public PracticeButtons()
        {
            var btn1 = new CardTemplate() { };
            btn1.SetBinding(CardTemplate.TapCommandProperty, "ABtnCmd");
            btn1.SetBinding(CardTemplate.TextAProperty, "ABtnTitleLabelA");
            btn1.SetBinding(CardTemplate.TextBProperty, "ABtnTitleLabelB");
            this.Children.Add(btn1, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have written below example.

**Home.xaml**

```
<Grid>
            <App1:PracticeButtons x:Name="Test" BindingContext="{Binding .}"/>
        </Grid>
```

**Home.xaml.cs**

```
public Home(){
           InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new ViewModel();

            BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
private string _ABtnTitleLabelA;
        
        public string ABtnTitleLabelA
        {
            get => _ABtnTitleLabelA;
            set
            {
                _ABtnTitleLabelA = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
            propertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

public ViewModel()
        {
           
            _ABtnTitleLabelA = "Testttttt";
            
        }
}
```

**PracticeButton.cs**

```
public class PracticeButtons : Grid
    {
       
        public PracticeButtons()
        {
            var btn1 = new CardButtonTemplate();
            btn1.SetBinding(CardButtonTemplate.TextBProperty, "ABtnTitleLabelA");
            this.Children.Add(btn1, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

**CardButtonTemplate.cs**

```
public class CardButtonTemplate : StackLayout
    {
        public CardButtonTemplate()
        {
            this.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            this.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

            var TL = new Label()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            };
            TL.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("TextB", source: this));
            

            this.Children.Add(TL);
            
        }

        
        public static readonly BindableProperty TextBProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextB),
            typeof(string), typeof(Frame), default(string), propertyChanged: TextBPropertyPropertyChanged);
        

        
        public string TextB { get => (string)GetValue(TextBProperty); set => SetValue(TextBProperty, value); }
        
        private static void TextBPropertyPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)newValue))
            //{
            //    CardButtonTemplate cardButtonTemplate = bindable as CardButtonTemplate;
            //    cardButtonTemplate.firstRow.Height = 30;
            //    cardButtonTemplate.textA.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;

            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    CardButtonTemplate cardButtonTemplate = bindable as CardButtonTemplate;
            //}
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried exactly this: <studycards:PracticeButtons BindingContext="{Binding .}"/> but I still do not see the labels appearing and the command does not get called. Do you have any other suggestions I can try.  Note I removed , source: Parent from my code also.

Comment: Can you please provide your card template class?

Comment: Just want to mention that when I use the XAML <!--<buttons:CardPracticeButtons />--> then it works good

Comment: I have added an example in my answer. Please check.

Comment: I will check everything out in more detail.  Thanks

Comment: The "BindingContext="{Binding .}""  doesn't seem to make any difference.  What is giving the problem is when I have multiple buttons.  Having one or two buttons in the .cs file works but when I get up to four then the last couple don't get created properly.

Comment: I have changed the question to reflect what I have learned about the problem.

Comment: Not at all resolved.  Please see the updated question. All I did was find out how to simulate the failure by having three buttons in the grid.  Two work just fine.  Adding a 3rd (when the 3rd is same as 2nd button or different) doesn't work at all. Turns out that for 1 or 2 buttons the original code worked just fine.  Problem is when I add more buttons it fails and displays incorrectly.  See button 3 which should look same as button 2 in the image.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check. You will have to remove source:this from btn3 set binding method.